# html FileReader : convert blob to image file?

Tags: php, javascript, html

client side code

```
<head>
<script>
var reader = new FileReader(); 
var objVal;
var image = new Image();
reader.onload = function(e) {
    document.getElementById('propertyImg').setAttribute('src', e.target.result);
};

function readURL(input){    
    if(input.files && input.files[0]){
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
    else {
        document.images[0].src = input.value || "No file selected";
    }
}

function sendPost(){
            var url = 'http://myurl.com';
            var name = document.getElementById('fileInput').files[0].name;
    var data = document.getElementById('propertyImg').getAttribute('src');
    var f = document.createElement("form"); 
    var imgName = document.createElement("input"); 
    var imgData = document.createElement("input"); 
    var f_attr = { 'method' : 'post' , 'action' : url};
    var imgName_attr = {"type" : "hidden", "name" : "img_name", "value" : name};
    var imgData_attr = {"type" : "hidden", "name" : "data", "value" : data};
    setAttributes(f, f_attr);
    setAttributes(imgName, imgName_attr);
    setAttributes(imgData, imgData_attr);
    f.appendChild(imgName);
    f.appendChild(imgData);
    document.body.appendChild(f); 
    f.submit(); 
}

function setAttributes(el, attrs) {
    for(var key in attrs) {
        el.setAttribute(key, attrs[key]);
    }
}
</script>
<body>
   <img id="propertyImg" src="./img/sprite.png"></img>  
   <input type='file' id='fileInput'class='width70_prop' onchange="readURL(this);"></input>
   <button onclick="sendPost()">sendPost</button>
</body>
```

serverside code

```
<html>
    <head>
    <?
          $FileName = $_POST['img_name']; 
          $data = $_POST['data']; 
          list($header, $content) = split('[,]', $data); 
          file_put_contents($FileName, base64_decode($content));
          print "Data Written"; 
     ?>
    <script>
    function showImg(){
    var imgSrc =  "<?=$data?>";
    var imgDiv = document.getElementById('imgDiv');
    imgDiv.src = imgSrc;
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <img id='imgDiv'></img>
    <button onclick="showImg()">show</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

the blob sent to server had infomation about header and its content. 
when I split header then save decoded its content, it worked.... 
I changed above code which now works. thx guys

Comment: You're writing your file as a base64 string, you should really try decoding it first and maybe go for a xhr instead of that thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there isn't anything in `$_POST["data"]` because the index (data) is named by the key in the JSON `key : value` pair, not the JavaScript `var`.

Secondly, you should change this:

```
$Handle = fopen($FileName, 'w');
fwrite($Handle, $data); 
print "Data Written"; 
fclose($Handle);
```

to this:

```
file_put_contents($FileName, base64_decode($data));
```

Comment: thanks.. thanks!! blob sent header and content altogether. I splited header and content form blob then decoded content as u provided.. it worked... thx again

Answer (score 2):

oops.. someone beat me to it... 
When you read files as Dataurl on the clientside: reader.readAsDataUrl(...)
the file is encoded in to a base64 string..  That's why if you save the data directly, it's not in the correct format.
As the previous answer states, you base64_decode your data into the correct format.